# Django - makemigrations- app could not be found

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. I've seen variations of this questions and tried all the answers but nothing works. When trying to apply makemigrations on my app "products" it returns:

```
App 'products' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
```

I tried makemigrations using these variations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py makemigrations products
./manage.py makemigrations products
```

same result. I have 'products' on my INSTALLED_APPS list, I have the migrations folder under products and I have **init**.py file under products and migrations.

'products' also won't show on the admin interface even after importing it to to admin.py

ps: using django 2.0.7 because the tutorial I'm following asked to.

**Edit:**

It works but I don't really understand why. I'm using sublime text (asked by tutorial) and it didn't autosave. I changed the option and restarted everything and it worked. 'products' still doesn't show on the admin interface however.

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = ''

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'trydjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trydjango.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Assuming you have registered it in `admin.py`?

Comment: @MeL, thank you. dumb mistake: I forgot to add the model's name as argument to ```admin.site.register()```. It works. It would be nice if you can make your comment a post so I can mark it as the answer to help others.

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped! I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to register your app on `admin.py`, like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(models.Product)
```